# Is there a better way in Svelte to include a conditional HTML element

Tags: if-statement, svelte, code-duplication, svelte-3

I started to come across this problem a lot. I want to include an element around other elements if a boolean is true. In the example below I make two if statements, but if the code that I want to wrap is big this will make it unclear what is happening. Also, there will be duplicate code. Is there a better way to this solution?

```
<script>
   let boolean = true;
</script>

{#if}
   <img src="source" />
{/if}

{#if}
   <a href="/home">
      <img src="source" />
   </a>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is something you find yourself doing often, you could make a `ConditionalLink` component out of it using [slots](https://svelte.dev/docs#slot).

```html
<!-- ConditionalLink.svelte -->
<script>
    export let isWrapped = false;
    export let href;
</script>

{#if isWrapped}
<a {href}>
    <slot/>
</a>
{:else}
<slot/>
{/if}
```

It can be used like so:

```html
<script>
    import ConditionalLink from './ConditionalLink.svelte'; 
    let wrapLink = false;
</script>

<ConditionalLink isWrapped={wrapLink} href="#">
    I'm a link
</ConditionalLink>

<label><input type="checkbox" bind:checked={wrapLink}> wrap link</label>
```

Comment: Yup. For me the Litmus test of when to go with a wrapping component would be the complexity of what's in the slot. As soon as it becomes non trivial, I'd wrap the if logic in a component to avoid duplication of, well, non trivial markup.

Comment: Thanks! Had a feeling this was going to be one of the best ways